# bash: do different actions depending on python version installed

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have to install different modules according to the version of Python installed on a machine.

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141581/detect-python-version-in-shell-script) asked how to do this, but it only *prints* the result to screen. For instance:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.version_info'
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

or rather:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])))'
2.7.3
```

On a Bash shell, how can I "catch" the printed line above so that I can incorporate its value in an **if-statement**?

EDIT: OK, now I realize it was very simple. I got stuck initially with:

```
a=$(python --version)
```

... because it didn't assign anything to the variable `a`, it only printed the version to screen.

Comment: `python --version` outputs to `STDERR` due to which _it only printed the version to screen_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if [[ $(python --version 2>&1) == *2\.7\.3 ]]; then
  echo "Running python 2.7.3";
  # do something here
fi
```

Note that `python --version` outputs to `STDERR` so you'd need to redirect it to `STDOUT`.

In order to assign it to a variable,

```
a=$(python --version 2>&1)
```

Comment: ooh ok, that's what I was missing. How could I have figured it out on my own that it was printing to STDERR? Just by guessing and trying?

Comment: @RickyRobinson When it didn't redirect the output to the variable and printed on the screen instead, you could have said `python --version 2>/dev/null` to see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the value to a variable:

```
pyver=$(python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])))')
```

please, note that there are **no spaces** around the `=`.

Now, you can use it in your `if` statement:

```
if [[ "$pyver" == "2.7.0" ]]; then
    echo "Python 2.7.0 detected"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use command substiution (`` or $()):

```
if [ $(python ...)  == 2.7.3 ]
then
 ...
fi
```