# in python bash saying print is not a command

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am just starting to learn Python.

Yesterday I started python and got

```
>>>
```

I entered `hello world` and it worked.

Yet, today I get that bash doesn't recognize `print`.  I am working on a course from Coursera and it requires python 2.7.

How do I know if I have that or python 3?

Comment: Question not clear. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `python -v` checks version. Check [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141581/detect-python-version-in-shell-script) too..

Comment: bash and python are two completely different programs and languages.  Why are you mixing them?.

Comment: bash is correct, it does not have a `print` command, but python does.  You must enter `python` to get the python prompt `>>>`.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the comments, `bash` is a shell and command language while Python is a high-level programming language.

To get what you want in Python, use the `print` command

[image]

The `print` command does not exist in `bash`.  So use the `echo` command

[image]

results:

[image]

Comment: To answer their last question, use `python -vv` from `bash` to get python version number