# Bash Script Help: How to Create a command in a script based on matching characters in a file

Tags: python, regex, bash, pip, installation

I have a folder that will have a file name based on the python version being used.

```
PyICU-1.9.5-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_x86_64.whl
PyICU-1.9.5-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_x86_64.whl
```

I want to use bash to detect the `35` or `27`, and then execute a `pip install <filename>`.  I have [GitHub Gist that has this hard coded](https://gist.github.com/linwoodc3/fc7d986401671159484266c937d53b9c#file-polyglotonmacosxpython27-sh-L42-L51), but instead of Hard coding the filename, I would like to detect the version, pick the filename with that version, and use it in a new command.

I would like to change the `pip install` command based on the file name.  I found some code to detect the python version; what's the next piece?

```
#from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141581/detect-python-version-in-shell-script
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])'
```

How do I detect the numbers after cp, so that I can construct this:
detected `34`, so:
`pip installPyICU-1.9.5-cp34-cp34-macosx_10_6_x86_64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Assuming $ver holds the version string...
ver=$(echo "$ver" | awk -F - '{print $3}' | sed 's/^..//')
```

For a more detailed explanation;

`awk -F - '{print $3}'` uses `-` as the field separator and returns the third field. The third field in this example is returned as `cp34`.

`sed 's/^..//'` removes the first two characters, and returns the rest, in this case `34`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't even need to extract the version from the filename, but just execute the file that is in the folder, then you can do:

```
cd dist/ &&
filename=$(ls|grep 'PyICU-')
pip install $filename
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])'
> ```

This yields e. g. `(2, 7, 3, 'final', 0)`, while what you need for the file name would be just `27`, so we have to modify the above code a little:

```
python -c 'import sys; print("%s%s"%sys.version_info[:2])'
```

> what's the next piece?

Now we can set a variable to the output of the above and use it in the file name:

```
ver=`python -c 'import sys; print("%s%s"%sys.version_info[:2])'`
pip installPyICU-1.9.5-cp${ver}-cp${ver}-macosx_10_6_x86_64.whl
```