when running 'make' it tells me I dont have python installed?
I am running a sample program given to me through GitHub for the max780000fthr. I know that it works as my teammate was able to compile it - though it won't successfully work when flashed onto the microcontroller.
anyways, not the point, im having issues with the make command saying I dont have python. ive used python within the same directory to test a .py file so I do have it installed and working where im in -
ive even changed the zsh path on my Mac to the newest python on my Mac and im still having an issue with the 'make' command. what could the issue be? thank you for any help!
the output of running 'make':
annavladimirskaya@Annas-MacBook-Pro-6 mnist-riscv % vim test1.py
annavladimirskaya@Annas-MacBook-Pro-6 mnist-riscv % python test1.py
hello
annavladimirskaya@Annas-MacBook-Pro-6 mnist-riscv % python3 test1.py
hello
annavladimirskaya@Annas-MacBook-Pro-6 mnist-riscv % make 
//Users/annavladimirskaya/Documents/mdsk/msdk/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/Maxim/GCC/gcc.mk:55: No Python installation detected on your system!  Will not automatically update version info.
****************************************************************************
* Analog Devices MSDK
* v2024_02-149-gb9966ca6d8
* - User Guide: https://analogdevicesinc.github.io/msdk/USERGUIDE/
* - Get Support: https://www.analog.com/support/technical-support.html
* - Report Issues: https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/msdk/issues
* - Contributing: https://analogdevicesinc.github.io/msdk/CONTRIBUTING/
****************************************************************************
make[1]: arm-none-eabi-gcc: Command not found
- CC //Users/annavladimirskaya/Documents/mdsk/msdk/Libraries/CMSIS/../PeriphDrivers/Source/SYS/mxc_assert.c
make[2]: arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [//Users/annavladimirskaya/Documents/mdsk/msdk/Libraries/PeriphDrivers/bin/MAX78000/spi-v1_softfp/mxc_assert.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [//Users/annavladimirskaya/Documents/mdsk/msdk/Libraries/PeriphDrivers/bin/MAX78000/spi-v1_softfp/libPeriphDriver_spi-v1_softfp.a] Error 2
make: *** [arm] Error 2

the part of the makefile which generates the error:

ifeq "$(PYTHON_CMD)" ""
# Try python
ifneq "$(wildcard $(MAXIM_PATH)/.github)" ""
PYTHON_VERSION := $(shell python --version)
ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)
PYTHON_CMD := none
else
PYTHON_CMD := python
endif

# Try python3
ifeq "$(PYTHON_CMD)" "none"
PYTHON_VERSION := $(shell python3 --version)
ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)
PYTHON_CMD := none
else
PYTHON_CMD := python
endif
endif

# Export PYTHON_CMD so we don't check for it again unnecessarily
export PYTHON_CMD
endif

# Make sure script exists before running. This won't run when working in the official MSDK release (non-GitHub)
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(MAXIM_PATH)/.github)", "")
# Run script if exists.
ifneq "$(PYTHON_CMD)" "none"
UPDATE_VERSION_OUTPUT := $(shell python $(MAXIM_PATH)/.github/workflows/scripts/update_version.py)
else
$(warning No Python installation detected on your system!  Will not automatically update version info.)
endif 
endif
endif

ifneq "$(wildcard $(MAXIM_PATH)/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/Maxim/GCC/mxc_version.mk)" ""
include $(MAXIM_PATH)/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/Maxim/GCC/mxc_version.mk
endif


Could it be because shell is calling sh that link to other shell? Check /var/select/sh

What's the value of PYTHON_CMD within your environment? You may try setting it yourself to "python3"

You can try multiple ways to detect python. Answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141581/detect-python-version-in-shell-script provided multiple solution and you may check them out.

That make is not finding Python is puzzling, but it does not appear to be the reason your build is failing.  That is the result of arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory.

I see two possibilities: you haven't provided enough information for us to know the correct one.
First, are you positive that nothing in your makefiles is resetting the PATH variable?  It looks to me like the PATH make is providing to various shells is not correct.  As mentioned in the comments the biggest problem you have is that make can't find the correct compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc; it doesn't have anything to do with Python.
The other possibility is that you didn't say what version of GNU Make you have.  Apple provides an incredibly old, decrepit version of GNU Make with their environment (3.81, released in 2006).  The .SHELLSTATUS variable was introduced in GNU Make 4.2, which was released in 2016.  If you are using an older version of GNU Make then .SHELLSTATUS is never set and this might be why make says you have no Python installed.
